# Как сделать, чтобы этот код не съел трафик?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sel_preparat = mysql_query('SELECT prepar_name,city,organ_name,street,pharm_address,pharm_tel,prep_upd,price,new_price,discount,id_user,id_prep_user,ph7.user_id AS USID FROM pharm_copy ph1 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_preparation_user ph7 ON (ph7.id_pharm=ph1.id_copy_pharm AND ph7.activ=1) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_user ph2 ON (ph2.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_signup ph3 ON (ph3.id_user=ph1.id_pharm) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_street ph4 ON (ph4.id_street=ph3.id_street) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_region ph5 ON (ph5.id_region=ph4.id_region)  
               LEFT JOIN pharm_discount ph6 ON (ph6.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
               WHERE ph2.activ=0 AND ph7.prepar_name LIKE "%'.$search.'%"'.$filtr.$filtr1.$filtr2.$filtr3.$filtr4.$temp.$filtr5.$wh_price.' 
               GROUP BY ph7.prepar_name, ph7.price, ph7.city, ph1.id_pharm ASC '.$asc,$db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: он мне съел моск :)
оформите код как полагается, вставляйте только нужный кусок

Comment: а с чего он должен съедать трафик? да,запрос грузный, но вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: как можно оптизировить этот код, чтобы работал эффективно

Comment: без понятия, я вообще не совсем понимаю что это
>"%'.$search.'%"'.$filtr.$filtr1.$filtr2.$filtr3.$filtr4.$temp.$filtr5.$wh_price.' 

если на него не смотреть, то вроде все и так ок.

Comment: это php код

Comment: @Garnik спасибо я догадался

Comment: Что значит "не съел трафик"?

Answer (score 1):

Если вас интересует оптимизация - вам нужно:

1. набрать статистику по тому какие SQL
       запросы вы генерируете (то есть
       пресловутые
       `$filtr.$filtr1.$filtr2.$filtr3.$filtr4.$temp.$filtr5.$wh_price`)
2. Использовать команду [Explan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) для
       того что-бы понять что работает не
       так.
3. Добавить в select [USE
       INDEX/FORCE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) для того
       что-бы заставить mysql выполнять
       запрос как вы хотите